# iTunesArtwork - Needed in app bundle?

Tags: objective-c, ios, app-store, itunes, appstore-approval

We are trying to squeeze under the 50MB wifi limit for a new game for iOS we are working on.

Is there any reason to include iTunes artwork in an app's bundle? Including the 1024x1024 one and the 512x512 one?  iTunes connect requires a 1024x1024 icon when you submit an app on their website, so why is it needed in your app as well?

Reason I'm asking is that a 1024x1024 PNG is roughly 1MB, which would help us squeeze under 50MB.

Comment: As I know, iTunes artwork in an app's bundle needed only for ad-hoc...

Comment: Heres Apples requirements. No for bundle. Optional (but recommended) for ad hoc. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1686/_index.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I submitted an App yesterday without the iTunes Artworks in the App Bundle.

Imho it works

Comment: So, not needed in app-store builds at all?

Comment: No just upload it to iTunes Connect. It's just for the AppStore(s)

Comment: For Ad-Hoc it would use it for displaying the icon in iTunes.  The app store uses the uploaded version instead.